# android edit text doesn't accept numric input

Tags: android

I developing android application and this problem I've get stuck on since yesterday and I don't know what is the problem.

the edit text doesn't take numeric input. my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/dp5">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp15"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/home_et_code"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:hint="@string/code_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="18"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home_btn_charge"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="@string/charge"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

if I remove `android:inputType="number"` then it starts working and takes input, but I need the edit text to accept only numeric input.

I didn't handle anything in java yet. so no need to add the java code.

NOTE: it works fine on android > 14, but on Gingerbread devices the problem occurs 
what is the problem??

Comment: Give some example that you try to input via edittext.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur any number input like '12345567' the problem is when entering input the edittext keeps empty. but if I remove android:inputType='number' it works

Comment: Try to use this:  android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Comment: @AlexeyKorolev it didn't work

Comment: Interesting, maybe this:   android:inputType="phone" ?

Comment: @AlexeyKorolev didn't work. could it be the problem from the device I use for testing?? I'm using Google nexus 1 rooted. on my onePlus one it works fine

Comment: I've checked on virtual device with API 10 and it worked.

Comment: @AlexeyKorolev its not the first time that I test on nexus 1 but  its the first time this problem happen. after updating android sdk platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it works fine, because I updated android sdk platform I noticed a lot of problems like the edit text input also back button press is not detected in code. but all what I have to do is to close android studio and reopen it then I compile my application. finally it works again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:digits="1234567890"
```

try to put this line on your edittext